# Dash running in a PyQt QThread() - most appropriate way to re-initialize with new data

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, plotly-dash, qthread

At the moment I have a PyQt5 app running Dash in a QThread like so:

```py
class MapView(QObject):

    message = pyqtSignal(str)
    shutting_down = pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.app = dash.Dash(__name__)
        self.data = data
    
        #manual callbacks
        self.app.callback(
            Output('hover-data', 'children'),
            Input('basic-interactions', 'hoverData'))(self.display_hover_data)

        self.app.callback(
            Output('page-content', 'children'),
            Input('url', 'pathname'))(self.shutdown)
        
#...more callbacks

    def shutdown(self, pathname):
        if pathname != '/shutdown':
            return
        print("Trying to shutdown map dash")
        func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
        if func is None:
            raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
        func()
        self.shutting_down.emit(True)

#.....lots of stuff like graphs, the layout, a function to start the server etc
```

and then the threading code in my main pyqt5 app is:

```py
def show_map(self):
        
        self.mapthread = QThread()
        self.map = map_dash.MapView(self.data) 
        self.map.moveToThread(self.mapthread)
        self.map.message.connect(self.update_output)
        self.map.shutting_down.connect(self.close_map_thread)
        self.mapthread.finished.connect(self.open_project)
        self.mapthread.started.connect(self.map.run)
        self.mapthread.start()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('http://127.0.0.1:8050'))
        self.update_output("Map plotted.")
```

My initial problem here was that if I tried to run `show_map()` with new data when Dash was already running (the user goes to `File -> Open` when a project is already running) , I would get the fatal `Qthread: destroyed while thread is still running`. So I embarked along the path of shutting down the flask server, then closing the thread, then going back to the function that opens a new project. It's like this:

1. User goes to `File -> Open`
2. `def open_project()` checks `mapthread.isRunning()`
3. It's not running so it opens a new project, creates a new `QThread` and new `MapView` instance
4. User goes to `File -> Open` again
5. The check in (2) returns True so the flask server is asked to shut down
6. After the server has shut down, the shutting_down signal causes the thread to be asked to `quit()` (I'm not sure how robust this is because it isn't a signal from flask, just a line after I've asked it to shut down. But it seems to work for now).
7. Once the thread has finished, the thread emits `finished()` which calls `open_project()` again
8. `open_project` this time sees that the thread is not running and allows the user to open a new file.

4 to 8 doesn't take too long to run but it all seems a bit complicated and the Dash layout glitches a bit for whatever reason. As it stands, when the QThread finishes under any other circumstances it would call `open_project` (although I could probably work around that). Is there a better way to do this? Can I feed the existing map instance new data somehow? I have read the documentation on `dcc.Interval` but that doesn't seem a great way to do it either...

Update (as per comments below):

Now what I'm doing is passing new data to the thread `self.map.data = new_data`, then using a callback on url to re-draw the map and refresh the layout. Exactly like this:

```py
    elif pathname == '/refresh':
            self.draw_map()
            self.set_layout()
```

But here is the problem. `self.set_layout()` refreshes dash with the OLD figure. I have verified that `self.draw_map()` is drawing a new figure. But calling /refresh a second time does cause dash to use the new figure. So is dash storing the old figure in a cache that hasn't been updated in the fraction of a second it takes to set the layout again? How can I make dash wait for the cache to be updated?

Comment: At the moment I'm trying to simply pass the new data into the thread (`self.map.data = new_data') which seems to work in that the dash layout can no longer access the old data, but it also can't access the new data either.

Comment: Passing data into the thread works if I then setup a callback on a url like /refresh which redraws the map and reloads the layout. However, it's unreliable and usually /refresh needs to be called twice for changes to actually be seen. So this isn't a good solution for now.

Comment: I believe the need for restarting the app is a symptom of a bad design. Why don't you just store the data in a serverside cache (e.g. on disk, in Redis, ...) and access it in callbacks?

Comment: I agree.

The data is already stored server-side - this is part of a pyqt5 app and the dash is used for data visualisation. As I said above the data can be passed into the running thread but attempts to refresh the dash to show the new data using callbacks have been hit and miss. It works best when 'refresh' is assigned to a button that the user clicks (twice) and dash will then show the new data. I will play with having the dash app check to see if the figure is actually different from the last one it drew and if not, reload the layout and draw the figures again.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to pass the new data into the dash instance

`self.map.data = new_data`

but this does not refresh the layout and you can't simply call

`self.map.set_layout()` from the main thread. Instead you have to use the url callback like this:

```py
def shutdown(self, pathname):
        if pathname == '/shutdown':
            print("Trying to shutdown map dash")
            func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
            if func is None:
                raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
            func()
            self.shutting_down.emit(True)
        elif pathname == '/refresh':
            self.draw_map()
            self.set_layout()
```

of course it would be more appropriate to call that method something like `handle_url()` now.

But there is a further problem. I'm guessing due to some caching issue, dash displays the old version of the figure unless the user manually calls refresh again. The solution is to add a `dcc.Interval` callback that updates the figure (it calls `draw_map()`). It doesn't need to be doing this every second, you can set the interval to 999999, for example. In fact you can set 'max_intervals=1' and it still works. As long as the callback is there, it will be called the first time the page refreshes and the figure will be updated.

In fact, with that in place, the `draw_map()` and `set_layout()` functions don't even need to be called in the url callback. So the code now looks like this:

```py
def shutdown(self, pathname):
        if pathname == '/shutdown':
            print("Trying to shutdown map dash")
            func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
            if func is None:
                raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
            func()
            self.shutting_down.emit(True)
        elif pathname == '/refresh':
            print("I'm doing nothing")
```

And it works. But the url callback itself IS necessary.